# How to hash an already hashed value for a given range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, md5, hashlib

I'm trying to design a One-Time-Password algorithm. I want to get a string input from the user and hash it repeatedly for a 100 times, then store each into an array. I'm stuck on the part that requires repeatedly hashing the string.

I've tried the basics, I know how to get the hash of a string value once using hashlib. In the code below, I tried applying it this way to do it for 10 times, but I feel like there's an easier way that actually works.

```
import hashlib

hashStore= []

password= input("Password to hash converter: ")
hashedPassword= hashlib.md5(password.encode())
print("Your hash is: ", hashedPassword.hexdigest())

while i in range(1,10):
    reHash= hashlib.md5(hashedPassword)
    hashStore.append(rehash)
    i= i+1
    print("Rehashed ",reHash.hexdigest())
```

However this code doesn't work. I'm expecting it to "re-hash" the value and each time it does so add it to the array.

Any and all help is appreciated :)

Comment: `rehash` and `reHash` are different variables. Watch your coding standards. You also never prime the loop (i.e. `i = 0`). This code should have errored out in several spots.  You may just want to use a `for` loop instead of priming a `while` loop: `for _ in range(1, 10):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For-loops in Python can be implemented easier. Just write `for i in range(10):` without anything in the loop inside.
2. `hashStore.append(rehash)` uses `rehash` instead of `reHash`
3. You don't memoize your `reHash` so you are always try to hash the starting string
4. You should convert your hash to string if you want to rehash it: `reHash.hexdigest().encode('utf-8')`

Here is the full working code:

```
import hashlib

hashStore = []

password = input("Password to hash converter: ")
hashedPassword = hashlib.md5(password.encode())
print("Your hash is: ", hashedPassword.hexdigest())
reHash = hashedPassword
for i in range(10):
    reHash = hashlib.md5(reHash.hexdigest().encode('utf-8'))
    hashStore.append(reHash)
    print("Rehashed ",reHash.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Yes, this works thank you! I didn't know about the conversion part, learned something new today.

Comment: `for i in range(1,10):` will loop only 9 times.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop instead, initialize the `hashStore` with the initial hash, and rehash the last hashed hash (`hashStore[-1]`) in each loop:

```
import hashlib

password= input("Password to hash converter: ")
hashedPassword= hashlib.md5(password.encode())
print("Your hash is: ", hashedPassword.hexdigest())

hashStore= [hashedPassword]
for _ in range(1,100):
    reHash = hashlib.md5(hashStore[-1].hexdigest().encode('utf-8'))
    hashStore.append(reHash)
    print("Rehashed ",reHash.hexdigest())
```